# MATLAB used up all my disk space! How can I get it back?

Tags: matlab, diskspace

I left MATLAB running on a simple ode45 + plot, and when I came back I saw that the 5GBs of free space I had on my drive (C:) was no more! MATLAB had stopped due to "no memory".

Can someone please tell me what happened and how I can get my space back???

Thank You.

Comment: Probably the swap file has allocated the remaining 5GB of space.

Comment: out of memory is not a hard drive errors, that is a RAM issue. How big are the matrices you are handling and how RAM do you have?

Comment: @Daniel - What swap file? It'd be a real help if you could elaborate.

Comment: @user3532586: When your RAM is full, your operating system moves some of the data to your hard disk. Plese check your OS documentation for more details.

Comment: @MZimmerman6 - I know that's a RAM issue, but I just can't find any other thing that might have done this. I have 4GB of RAM, and I think the matrices go about 42x4 (i think!)...
I could just give you the code, it's hardly anything at all...

Comment: @Daniel - ohh, I just remembered that. But, doesn't swapping have a limit? Or is the default probably whatever empty space the os drive has?...

Answer (score 2):

You can visually inspect hard disk usage and find folders and files which take up a lot of space with a tool such as [TreeSize Free](http://www.jam-software.com/freeware/).

[image]

P.S. You can also try clearing temporary folders either trough built-in disk cleaner or other tools such as [CCleaner](https://www.piriform.com/ccleaner).

Comment: Well, the disk cleaner yielded nothing. And I used Xinorbis to find recent and/or big files. But it came up with nothing associated to MATLAB. The biggest files were system files (.sys)...

Comment: @Illidan Then I would suggest inspecting the page file (or swap) allocation, as already mentioned in other comments.

Comment: Well, a complete sys reboot did the job. But what's weird for me is that the paging limit was increased from 4GBs to 9GBs, and would've kept going if I still had space left. Why would the OS allow that???

Comment: @Illidan Windows allows you to set a variable (on-demand) page file size by specifying a range (initial and maximum). I guess it could be useful in some situations. I always change this setting to a fixed size. You can change it in System -> Advanced system settings -> Performance options -> Virtual memory (configuration path varies with version of Windows).

Comment: Yes, I know of the virtual memory options; just didn't think the system itself would allow such usage. Anyway, I set the initial and maximum values at the same amount so it's fixed. Thanks for reminding me.

Answer (score 0):

MatLab is one of those apps that have an all world of computing science where you only want to work in a small tiny island of knowledge, the Help folder of it is huge, anyway here's some things you can do to make it slimmer on disk:

- Install only the packages you need.
- Use JPEGMini to compress the JPEG collection of the huge help folder.
- Use Pngyu to compress the huge collection of PNG files to 8 bit depth.
  Step 2 and 3 will get you back like a Gigabyte if not more.
- Use NTFS compression on the MatLab Folder.
  It will get you back another 2 Gigabytes

Both step 2 and 3 must be done with admin privileges, the drag and drop of folder to it must be done with another app with admin privileges also, you can use Explorer++ as Windows File Explorer alternative.